# How do I change the thousands separator of my default locale?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, locale, iostream

I can do

```
locale loc(""); // use default locale
cout.imbue( loc );
cout << << "i: " << int(123456) << " f: " << float(3.14) << "\n";
```

and it will output:

```
i: 123.456 f: 3,14
```

on my system. (german windows)

I would like to avoid getting the thousands separator for ints -- how can I do this?

(I just want the users default settings but without any thousands separator.)

(All I [found](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/numpunct/thousands_sep/) is how to *read* the thousands separator using `use_facet` with the `numpunct` facet ... but how do I change it?)

Comment: Are you open to work arounds, or must we modify the thousands separator? I have the feeling `printf` will print in the format you want, and also converting it to a string before printing will most likely achieve the desired result.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal - I really want a solution with no workaround and especially without printf. I just want the users default settings but *without* any thousands separator.

Comment: Cry because IOstreams and locales suck.

Comment: @DeadMG - indeed. Especially how they're (not) documented sucks big time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just create and imbue your own [numpunct](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/numpunct/) facet:

```
struct no_separator : std::numpunct<char> {
protected:
    virtual string_type do_grouping() const 
        { return "\000"; } // groups of 0 (disable)
};

int main() {
    locale loc("");
    // imbue loc and add your own facet:
    cout.imbue( locale(loc, new no_separator()) );
    cout << "i: " << int(123456) << " f: " << float(3.14) << "\n";
}
```

If you have to create a specific output for another application to read, you may also want to override `virtual char_type numpunct::do_decimal_point() const;`.

If you want to use a specific locale as base, you can derive from the `_byname` facets:

```
template <class charT>
struct no_separator : public std::numpunct_byname<charT> {
    explicit no_separator(const char* name, size_t refs=0)
        : std::numpunct_byname<charT>(name,refs) {}
protected:
    virtual string_type do_grouping() const
        { return "\000"; } // groups of 0 (disable)
};

int main() {
    cout.imbue( locale(std::locale(""),  // use default locale
        // create no_separator facet based on german locale
        new no_separator<char>("German_germany")) );
    cout << "i: " << int(123456) << " f: " << float(3.14) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by `"\000"` - that's a NUL followed by two zeroes, isn't it?

Comment: @MartinBa It's a null expressed in such a way that if the next character is an octal digit it won't change to another character (you can't do that with hexadecimal notation which hasn't a bounded number of characters).

Comment: @MartinBa the `\nnn`escape sequence is actually octal. That facet allows you to create a custom sequence like `"\001\003\002"` which would result in a `12.345.6` grouping.